# How to make a speedrun timer stay to the front

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I made an in game timer for Minecraft to use while speedrunning and it works great but the one problem is that when I make Minecraft fill my whole screen NOT FULLSCREEN just cover it the timer disappears.

I knew this would happen and I am wondering if this is possible to fix and make the pygame window go to the front even if it is blocked by an app that you are currently using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [`Tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html):

This way, you can make a timer:

1. Always put to front
2. Transparent

Furthermore, tkinter is in the Standard library.

You can use this code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread
from time import time

tk = Tk()
tk.title('Timer')
tk.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1) # put the window to front

pause = True
start = time()
time_when_paused = time() # time displayed when in pause

def restart(): # restart to 0
    global pause, start
    pause = False
    start = time()

def toggle_pause():
    global pause, start, time_when_paused
    pause = not pause
    if pause:
        time_when_paused = time() # update the time displayed
    else:
        start += time() - time_when_paused # forget the time passed in pause

def timer():
    while True:
        if pause:
            label['text'] = '%.2f' %(time_when_paused - start) # %.2f for 2 decimals
            label['fg'] = 'orange'
        else:
            label['text'] = '%.2f' %(time() - start)
            label['fg'] = 'green'

label = Label(tk, '', font=('Helvetica', 30), fg='orange')
label.grid(columnspan=2) # display the timer

# buttons
restart_button = Button(tk, text='Restart', width=20, command=restart)
restart_button.grid(padx=5, pady=5)
pause_button = Button(tk, text='Pause', width=20, command=toggle_pause)
pause_button.grid(padx=(0, 5), column=1, row=1)

timer_thread = Thread(target=timer)
timer_thread.start() # put in a thread because of...

tk.mainloop() # ...this which acts like "while window is not closed"
```

Comment: that you for taking your time to help me. I am very grateful and so far this works amazing.

Comment: Also you can use [LiveSplit](https://livesplit.org/) and [Borderless Gaming](https://github.com/Codeusa/Borderless-Gaming/releases).